# How to put error message inside Placeholder

Tags: javascript, message

I have found this Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/2650/ which allow entering only numbers in input field. Now I want to put inside input field `Placeholder` which will also be error message (look at Jsfiddle).

```
Number : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" placeholder="Test" />
```

And for error message is:

```
<span id="errmsg"></span>
```

Now I whant to do this: First you see input field with placeholder "Test". So if you put numbers, placeholder deletes, and you see only numbers that you enter. But If you put non-digit chars (letters), placeholder changes into error message `id="errmsg"`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like horrible UX. Why would you want to display an error message as the contents of an input field? Nobody does that, with good reason.

Comment: I just ask if its possible. But thanks for advice. I am new at this :) please no hard fillings.

Comment: Well it is possible indeed, but the user will only see the error message when the field is cleared. Doesn't sound very useful. Also you can clear the input but I wouldn't be pleased with that if I just entered, say, 30 numbers.

Comment: owww I got it :) realy thanks, I totaly forgot for thi scenario. So if user would first enter some digits, and than some letters, error message would shown after he delete message. Ok, realy thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this

```
 $("#quantity").attr("placeholder","errmsg");
```

**Fiddle:** [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/HkEuf/2651/)

Comment: The user will only see the error message when they clear the field though.

Comment: can you udate jsfiddle :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I figureout scenario, which would this solution not be good. See my comments.

Comment: @krnekires:  okies.. I only answered as per your question.. and it was possible to do so... ;) however user has to clear the text to see the placeholder message.

Comment: exactly, I forgot for thi scenario. But your answer is useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58221/discussion-between-sid-m-and-kr-neki-res).